# How can I get JavaScript to parse a parse and pass it in an API call

Tags: javascript

I have an API which I'd like to call through client-side JavaScript. I need to parse a URL parameter `ref` which then needs to be passed to the API call. For example:

I visit this page `www.example.com?ref=123`, JavaScript parses `ref` and passes it to `/api/v1.0/add?ref=123` and sends the request.

How can i do this?

Edit - Other answers show parsing the URL not making the API call.

Comment: You [read the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and append it to the query string your forwarding,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var url_string = "http://www.example.com?ref=123";
var url = new URL(url_string);
var ref = url.searchParams.get("ref");
var urlGet = '/api/v1.0/add?ref=' + ref

$.get( urlGet , function( data ) {   

});
```

André

Answer (score 0):

For that you may use [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function, as follows:

```
var input = 123;
var url = "/api/v1.0/add?ref="+input;
$.get( url, function( data ) {   

       // data is the return value, if any. You may use this return value, data, over here 

    });
```

Comment: Thanks - How would I put them both together? Sorry, I'm new to JS coming from Python background

Comment: Didn't get you?